# Multiple days (Creditenddate = $end1 $end2

Tags: for-loop, sms, send

```
$Credits = Credit::model()->findAll("CreditStatusID = '4' and CreditEndDate='".$EndDate."'");
```

Hello, please review code above and help me to add more $EndDate, $EndDate2,...

Comment: For code review there is another site. As for adding more $EndDate etc you kinda have to explain what you want to do.

Comment: ("CreditStatusID = '6' AND (CreditEndDate='".$EndDate5."' OR  CreditEndDate='".$EndDate10."') "); 

I need to add EndDate11,EndDate12 and etc

Comment: You just added another. So add yet another. What is the problem? Also the relevance to SMS, send or for-loop?

Comment: I mean will it work like: CreditEndDate='".$EndDate5."' OR CreditEndDate='".$EndDate10." OR '".$EndDate10."' OR...